# Excel macros run through powershell but not when run by windows task scheduler

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, windows-server-2012

I have a script which checks a folder for excel files and then if this "threshold" is greater than  0 then a macro from another excel file is run that interact with these excel folders.

When I run the process manually through powershell ISE it works fine but when I use the windows task scheduler the powershell script runs but the excel macro called doesn't run. Any suggestions why this might be the case? This process used to run on a windows 2008 server fine but was migrated to windows server 2012 and won't run properly

```
  if ($count -gt $threshold){
    $excel = new-object -comobject excel.application

    $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open("D:\TimesheetService\IS-FS - AutoTimesheetLoader v2.3 - UAT.xlsm")

    $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)

    $excel.Run("ImportTime")

    $workbook.close($false)

    $excel.quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
    Remove-Variable excel
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/579900/why-cant-excel-open-a-file-when-run-from-task-scheduler. BTW: Why do you use the `MacOS`-Tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot use the COM Automation Excel library** (`new-object -comobject excel.application`) from a scheduled task, **unless that task is run *in the window station (session) of the currently logged-on user***.

That is, in order to use the COM Excel library from a scheduled task, you must have the `Run only when user is logged on` option chosen for it, which you may not want, for two reasons:

- It restricts your task to run only when someone happens to be logged on.
- The currently logged-on user will *see* the task's window as it runs - unless you take extra steps to hide it (which can't be done with `powershell.exe` itself).

<sup>Note: There is **a workaround that is currently *effective*, but it is *unsupported***, which is why it is **better to avoid i**t - see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/655458/139307) to a related superuser.com question.</sup>

Therefore, **consider alternatives that do not have this restriction**, such as the [DocumentFormat.OpenXml Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/).

See [this Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) for background information.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing.  This got it working for me https://www.jonashendrickx.com/2016/04/07/when-run-as-scheduled-task-excel-wont-save-with-powershell/

The last two steps is what I needed.  Check to make sure these folders exist

On a 32-bit and 64-bit operating system:

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

On a 64-bit operating system:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop