# PowerShell Script running from bamboo, giving an error You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell

Below code when I'm running it from local it's working fine. However, when it is called from the bamboo scheduled job it runs on remote machines, it's failing with an error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." on the below code lines. Can someone please guide me on this?

```
Function runMacro(){

param([String]$excelFilePath,[String]$macroName,[String]$parameter)

try {
    if(Test-Path $excelFilePath)
    {
    $excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
    $excel.Visible = $false
    $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($excelFilePath)
    $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
    $excel.Run($macroName,$parameter)
    $workbook.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us how you are calling that function

Comment: Do you have excel installed on a machine that runs this script?

Comment: I'm assuming that the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60041657/45375) addresses your question.

Comment: @Grzegorz Ochlik, Yes. I've excel installed on the remote machine.

Comment: @theo Please find below code snippet to see the function call.
runMacro -excelFilePath $excelPath -macroName $testType -parameter $url